# C++ minimum string width

Tags: c++, iostream

Suppose I have

```
string a = "foo";
```

How can I print `a` to the console using `printf` that ensure a minimum width, say, 10?

Comment: As you are using C++ you should be using `cout`

Comment: you're right, I just didn't know I can do that with `cout`

Comment: Everything that you can do with `printf` your can do with `cout`. Also with `cout` you get the luxury of being type safe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`setw`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setw/) *manipulator* to set the width of the output, like this:

```
cout << setw(10) << a << endl;
```

The `iomanip` header needs to be included in order for this to compile.

Comment: Oops, I saw the C++ tag, but missed the `printf` portion of your question. For printf you need to use `%10s`, but that's more C than C++ (although it is a perfectly valid C++ code).

Comment: The comment is not necessary. Suggesting C++ solutions to C code tagged as C++ should be the default on SO. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
printf("%10s\n", a.c_str());
```

The above will right justify the string in the field. If you want left justification, use `%-10s` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`printf("%10s", a.c_str());`

[filler]